# Is there a way to transfer money between Square accounts?

Tags: square-connect

Is there a square API for transfering money between two square accounts?
I see the cash.me site,is there an API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no means to transfer funds between two Square accounts.